# How to make a 'stacked' gantt chart using Plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, gantt-chart

Please be patient as I'm quite new to posting on here/R.

I'm looking to create a gantt chart using Plotly in R, but for each task I will have multiple entries e.g. a task starts at 10:00 - 11:00, then stops and resumes at 13:00 - 14:00 etc, so each 'row' would have multiple lines.

I can do this easily in ggplot, but it just looks so much better in plotly - however I'm not having too much success!

My code in ggplot is like so:

```
library(chron)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

gc1<-data.frame(item = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                project_element = c("Task 1", "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Task 4"), 
                activity = c("do this", "do this", "do that", "and again", "double time"), 
                start_time = c(45.50, 65.70, 25.03, 10.3, 11.02), 
                duration = c(10.0, 34.8, 10.1, 78.9, 5.0))

#make a column specifying start/end times and convert to time. 
gc2<-gc1 %>%
  mutate(end_time = start_time+duration) %>%
  gather("state", "time", 4,6) %>%
  mutate(time = chron(times=time),
         duration = chron(times=duration))


ggplot(gc2, aes(time, activity, color = project_element, group=item)) +
  geom_line(size = 10) +
  labs(x="seconds(k)", y=NULL, title="Project timeline")
```

Comment: Hi Jessica! Thanks for an (almost) reproducible example. Can you please include `library()` calls in your code chunk? I don't know where `chron()` comes from.

Comment: @jakub apologies! I have done so now, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks. Next, I'd like to understand your question better. To create a plotly plot out of a ggplot object, you can just give it a name, e.g. `my_plot = ggplot(gc2, ...)` and then call `plotly::ggplotly(my_plot)`. The looks of it will be pretty much the same though, but you will gain responsiveness and pop-up labels. What exactly are you after?

Comment: @jakub I didn't know you could do this! It has worked great, I essentially wanted the interactivity of plotly - which your suggestion allows me to do. Now to find out how to customise it all!